# Cognos 11 Analytics

Tags: cognos-11

First time posting.
Our fire response agency just moved to Cognos 11 after qRep.  I know little to nothing about SQL, modules, cubes, or data analytics, but I'm one of the few in our agency that can write an excel function so I guess I am considered the in-house data expert.

With that in mind, I need some help.
I want to compare a calculated result (time interval) to a static goal.  For instance, if the calculated result is 01:00, how do I express a static goal of 01:20 as a time interval to make the calculation work?

Here is the formula I used for my "Static Goal" column:

```
IF([Inc Cat]='EMS') then ('60')) else
IF([Inc Cat]='FIRE') then ('80')) else
NULL
```

I need to convert the 60 and 80 above as seconds so I can compare a calculated time interval to these values.

I appreciate any help, but please review the second sentence of this post prior to replying.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I removed the single quotes and wrote out the complete time.

IF([Inc Cat]='EMS') then (0 00:01:10.000) else
IF([Inc Cat]='FIRE') then (0 00:01:20.000) else
NULL

Comment: A case statement would be aesthetically cleaner.

You've just discovered the concept of data types.   

I have the sinking feeling you're doing this entirely in a report without much in your model.  Please don't do that.   

If you want the value for EMS to be 60 seconds why are you making it 1 minute 10 seconds?